# Error NoReverseMatch

Tags: python-3.x, django

Olá, estou com o seguinte erro em uma aplicação em Django.

> NoReverseMatch at /row/details/2 Reverse for 'get-weatherdata' with
>   keyword arguments '{'rowId': 1, 'sensorId': 1}' not found. 1
>   pattern(s) tried: ['api/weatherData/$'] Request Method:   GET Request
>   URL:  http://localhost:8000/row/details/2 Django Version: 2.2.5
>   Exception Type:   NoReverseMatch Exception Value:  Reverse for
>   'get-weatherdata' with keyword arguments '{'rowId': 1, 'sensorId': 1}'
>   not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['api/weatherData/$']

Estou precisando passar como parâmetro para a api/weatherdata dois identificadores. Não sei se estou fazendo corretamente, mas segue os demais códigos

views.py

```
def get_weatherData(request, rowId, sensorId):
    weatherData = WeatherData.objects.filter(row_id=rowId, sensor_id=sensorId)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^api/weatherData/$', get_weatherData, name='get-weatherdata'),
```

index.html

```
<script>
{% block jquery %}
var endpoint = '/api/weatherData/'
var defaultData = []
var labels = [];
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
        labels = data.date
        defaultData = data.value
        setChart(labels, defaultData)
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})
{% endblock %}
</script>
<div class="container" url-endpoint='{% url "get-weatherdata" rowId=1 sensorId=1 %}'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está enviando parâmetros no *template* e também os recebendo na *view* mas não existe uma rota em *urls* que satisfaça esta condição, assim, acrescente os parâmetros nela.

```py
    url(
        r'^api/weatherData/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$',
        get_weatherData,
        name='get-weatherdata'
    ),
```

Na versão 2.x do Django foi introduzida a `path()` que é bem mais clara para definir a sintaxe das URL que as *regex* da `url()`.